# Why `systemctl stop service` can't invoke the service?

Tags: systemd, startx, start-stop-daemon

```
vim /home/mytest.sh
rm -f /home/mytest/*
```

I want to write a service to execute the remove action.
My expections:
`sudo systemctl stop mytest` can delete files in /home/mytest
`sudo systemctl start mytest` do nothing.

Edit my service file.

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/mytest.service
[Unit]
Description=delete file

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/bin/bash /home/mytest.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable it.

```
sudo systemctl enable mytest
```

Now i found a strange action for mytest service.

`sudo systemctl start mytest` can delete files in /home/mytest
`sudo systemctl stop mytest` do nothing.

Why?
Pleas give a explanation in detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained in detail in [the systemd service documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html), but you pretty much need to read all of it to understand what’s going on. The most pertinent part in this case is example 3; from that, the reader can gather that a oneshot service as you’ve declared it never becomes active, so its stop action will be run once its start action completes.

To achieve what you’re after, you need a oneshot service which nevertheless becomes active:

```
[Unit]
Description=delete file

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStop=/bin/bash /home/mytest.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `systemd` tracks all the processes it starts through cgroups, and unless you specify `RemainAfterExit=yes`, it won't maintain the state information "yes, mytest.service was run and should be considered still enabled although there are no processes left in its cgroup."

Without `RemainAfterExit=yes`, `systemctl stop mytest` makes `systemd` just take a look at the `systemd/system.slice/mytest.service` cgroup, and as there are no processes in it, it just thinks "it seems to be already stopped, so... nothing to do there!"